# Number of diseases and correlations

Tags: probability, causality

> In one country, there are exactly two types of diseases, perfectly
> independent. Let A: "person has first disease", B: "person has second
> disease". We assume that P(A) = 0.1; P(B) = 0.1
>
> Now anyone who has one of these diseases goes to the doctor and only
> then. Call C: "person goes to the doctor". We have C = A or B.
>
> Now let's calculate some probabilities: P(C) = 0.19; P(A|C) = P(B|C) =
> (0.1)/(0.19) ≈ 0.53; P(A ^ B|C) = (0.1)/(0.19) ≈ 0.53; P(A|C)P(B|C) ≈
> 0.28
>
> Clearly, when conditioned on C, A and B are far from independent. In
> fact, conditioning on C, not-A seems to "cause" B. If the list of
> people who were recorded by their doctors is used as a data source for
> an analysis, then there seems to be a strong correlation between
> diseases A and B. You may not be aware of the fact that your data
> source is actually a conditioning. This is also called selection bias.
> The point means that when A and B cause C, noting a correlation
> between A and B in cases where C is true doesn't mean that there is a
> real relationship between A and B. It's just conditioning on C
> (perhaps grudgingly) that creates an artificial correlation." I have a
> doubt about this explanation: If A and B are independent, then P(A
> inter B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.01... no? Another detail is that C = A or B
> if and only if all people who have at least one disease go to the
> doctor

I have a doubt about this explanation: If A and B are independent, then P(A inter B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.01... no? Another detail is that C = A or B if and only if all people who have at least one disease go to the doctor.  If C is defined as A or B, then does it imply that P(A inter B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.01 ? I'd like to know what you'd like to imply from that too

Comment: What's the source of this quote?

Answer (score 0):

The quoted paragraph defined C = A or B, I'm not sure what you are asking by saying "if and only if all people who have at least one disease go to the doctor". That's precisely how this person defined it.

$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) = 0.01$, yes.

On the other hand,

$$P(C) = P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = 0.19.$$

The passage is explaining the bias of using a data source coming from the doctors' offices only, artificially causing diseases A and B to have correlations.

Answer (score 0):

How one chooses to define $C$ says nothing at all about the relationship between $A$ and $B$. Whether we define $C$ as "$A \cup B$" or "$A \cap B$" or "FALSE" or "TRUE", it implies absolutely nothing about the independence or joint probability of $A$ and $B$. We can define $C$ however we want in the context of $A$ and $B$, whatever definition we choose has no impact on how $A$ and $B$ are related to each other.

It's the independence of $A$ and $B$ that implies $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. The definition of $C$, whatever it is, does not imply any kind of relationship between $A$ and $B$.